# C# - System.ObectDisposedException in MemoryStream for Capacity, Length, and Position Properties

Tags: dispose, idisposable, memorystream

When executing the code to render PDF file from Html Stream, code seems to be executing fine, but PDF is not generated.

When debugging through the code, it seems that everything works just fine until I do not start looking into `MemoryStream` object properties and notice the following under `MemoryStream` object:

[image]
This is the code:

```
public partial class WriteNotes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     ...
     protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
     {
        ...
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream printStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter printStreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(printStream))
        using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter printWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(printStreamWriter))
        {
            base.Render(printWriter);
            printWriter.Flush();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(printStream))
            {
               myStreamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
               Document pdfDocument = pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlStream(myStreamReader.BaseStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "/"));
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
               HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
               pdfDocument.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
               HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Executing the following line of code produces the described exception for MemoryStream.

```
Document pdfDocument = pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlStream(myStreamReader.BaseStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "/"));
```

The same kind of exception happens if I do not use `Disposable Pattern`.

The same code is in production and works fine.

What can be the reason?

Comment: What happens if you remove the last line or move it outside of the using blocks so its the last line of the method? HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

Comment: Nothing happens, the same blank pdf page

Comment: If its a blank page or object disposed exception then it looks like the pdf stream is not being flushed before the stream its writting to is closed. Make sure that stream is flushed first although I am not sure what object pdfDocument is and what is available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure enough, found it. Read the documentation here:

[PdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlStream(htmlStream, streamEncoding)](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/docs/html-to-pdf-library/html/d1081d96-87ef-1eca-0925-718c6d120ad2.htm)

In a nutshell it says to close the document object which you are not doing in your code above.

[PdfDocument.Close()](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/docs/html-to-pdf-library/html/82af9335-3aee-c345-9dad-a16de654a164.htm)

States it here too, always call method close on the document object once you are done with it. Try this updated code.

Also add the library you are using next time if you happen to know it. Some answers can be found right in the documentation (not all the time of course).

```
public partial class WriteNotes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     ...
     protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
     {
        ...
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream printStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter printStreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(printStream))
        using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter printWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(printStreamWriter))
        {
            base.Render(printWriter);
            printWriter.Flush();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(printStream))
            {
               myStreamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
               Document pdfDocument = pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlStream(myStreamReader.BaseStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "/"));
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
               HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
               pdfDocument.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

               pdfDocument.Close(); // add this line and see what happens

               HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
               HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: All the same, @Igor. Why do I get an exception on `MemoryStream` object like I mentioned in my post? Somehow, `MemoryStream` has exceptions. Initially, after `printWriter.Flush()`, its capacity is 830, but after executing the mentioned statement `...pdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlStream(...)`, it is capacity, length,and Position properties throw a specified exception. Is is possible that there is something else wrong?

Comment: Because pdfDocument probably writes to the stream that it was given in the Save method once you call Close() on it. Because you do not do this it will not get called until it *probably* hits a finalizer but once this runs the underlying streams you have created have already been disposed of hence the exception. I have to speculate a little here because I have no source code to view of the 3rd party api BUT I would follow their documentation and call Close() after you call Save() on PdfDocument.

Comment: But Save method is called after pdfDocument is created from the stream

Comment: Sure but the documentation states to call Close() immediatly after calling Save(). I do not know why they designed the API that way or what the reasoning is behind an extra call, sh*ty design perhaps or maybe there are more options that could be done that you don't need to take advantage of? The fact is though that they do state that you need to call Close after calling save.

Comment: So, basically, the exception I'm getting is not the reason why PDF is not displayed?

Comment: I think we are going in circles. Are you still having the problem after you added the statement pdfDocument.Close() per the above sample?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned before. All the same. As a matter of fact, the same code works on production environment. It does not work on development. Something else must be wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88409/discussion-between-igor-and-gene).